# CSS aligning radio/check button

Tags: css, forms, radio-button

My issue is trying to align my radio buttons so that they appear to the left of the text inputs on my form. After tweaking with CSS other week I got it working, now Ive reopened it and they are all misplaced again.

so if follow to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GEAuF/) and follow these instructions to get to where I am having the issue:

- select multi choice
- enter a number in 'No of options'

you should have a number of text inputs appear along with a radio button for each, I wish to align the radio button just to the left of the input.

Could somebody please tell me what the issue is?

many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are setting `width: 250px;` on your input. That includes these radio buttons. Since radio inputs don't support the width property, they are appearing centered and stretching that area.

Remove `width: 250px` for these radio buttons and adjust the styles from there.